# Magento Product Category Count

Tags: magento, count, categories

Currently, my categories have numbers next to them which are equal to the number of products of that category.

Example:

```
Category1 (5)

Category2 (23)

Category3 (1)
```

How can I remove those numbers?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a question about magento code, or the platform in general? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the product amount from the category by navigating to folder: /app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/catalog/navigation/

In the folder you should see some files (for example left.phtml). In this file you need to remove the following line of code `(<?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>)`

Comment: yes but i dont have such a folder in my custom theme folder, only in my base folder (i removed the code part but nothing happened)

Comment: If you have installed some extension that modifies the category style then you need to change the code in the extension. Otherwise you can try copying the file from base to your theme and see if it changes anything. Remember to update cache after making changes.

Comment: i have an extension but it also does not include such a folder, i tried to drag it into the extension folder and in the custom theme folder but it did not change anything

Comment: Most likely the extension has its own template file that it loads. ex: /app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/category_extension/extension_some_name.phtml
However if that file doesn't contain anything about the product count and instead has something like: `$this->getHtml()` then you need to navigate to app/code/community (or local)/extension_name/module_name/Block/some_php_file.php and remove the `(<?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>)` from there.

Comment: i can't find it :( is there another way to find the correct php file?